# List of valid resolutions for a given Screen?

Tags: c#, resolution

Is there a way to get ALL valid resolutions for a given screen?

I currently have a dropdown that is populated with all valid screens (using ***Screen.AllScreens***).  When the user selects a screen, I'd like to present them with a second dropdown listing *all* valid resolutions for that display (*not* just the current resolution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be possible to get the information using [Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation). WMI is accessible from .NET using the classes from them [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace.

A solution will look similar to the following. I don't know WMI well and could not immediately find the information you are looking for, but I found the WMI class for the resolutions supported by the video card. The code requires referencing System.Management.dll and importing the System.Management namespace.

```
var scope = new ManagementScope();

var query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM CIM_VideoControllerResolution");

using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
{
    var results = searcher.Get();

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "caption={0}, description={1} resolution={2}x{3} " +
            "colors={4} refresh rate={5}|{6}|{7} scan mode={8}",
            result["Caption"], result["Description"],
            result["HorizontalResolution"],
            result["VerticalResolution"],
            result["NumberOfColors"],
            result["MinRefreshRate"],
            result["RefreshRate"],
            result["MaxRefreshRate"],
            result["ScanMode"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Daniel.

I have been struggling with this for sometime now.  With your above answer, I don't see how it relates to individual screens.   With my dual displays setup, my video card may support up to 1900x1200, but my attached monitor has a max of 1280x1024.  I don't see how to query for the resolutions for the individual displays...

Comment: You will have to search through the available WMI classes ... I am quite confident that there is a class providing the information you are looking for. Go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394554(VS.85).aspx and search through the classes.

Comment: @DanielBrückner: How can I make this code to work with windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

The following link contains detailed code examples for this:

**Task 2: Changing the Display Resolution** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104(VS.71).aspx#docum_topic2

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to work on Windows 8.1, at least on my machine. The query runs fine but there are 0 entries in the results. And considering Bijoy K Jose's comment I suppose that I am not the only one.

However the validated answer for the following question worked out just fine :
[How to list available video modes using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744541/how-to-list-available-video-modes-using-c)

Thanks to Vimvq1987