# Available Resolutions For a specific Screen

Tags: c#, screen, resolution

I might have 2 monitor/screens connected to my machine.
I want to know all Avaliable resolutions for a specific screen (I have an instance of type System.Windows.Forms.Screen).

I've seen the following:
[How to list available video modes using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744541/how-to-list-available-video-modes-using-c)

[List of valid resolutions for a given Screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528266/list-of-valid-resolutions-for-a-given-screen)

but they all give results for all monitors and not just a specific one. Any suggestions? Thanks!!!

Edit 1:
[image]

This is the info about my 2 screens:
[image]

Comment: Basically, I tried to follow instructions in the above 2 links I've supplied.
But while debugging, I've seen that they return all resolutions for all monitors and I haven't seen any property that shows whether the current resolution belongs to my instance of Screen or the other one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first of those links you're told about `EnumDisplaySettings`. Take a few seconds to [lookup that function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162611(v=vs.85).aspx) and the **FIRST PARAMETER** is the

> string that specifies the display device about whose graphics mode the
>   function will obtain information.

Here's a sample class to fetch information about displays. I've deliberately omitted `DEVMODE` since you've already got it.

```
public class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool EnumDisplaySettings(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE devMode);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool EnumDisplayDevices(string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DISPLAY_DEVICE displayDevice, int flags);
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DISPLAY_DEVICE
{
    public int cb;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string DeviceName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string DeviceString;
    public int StateFlags;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string DeviceID;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string DeviceKey;
}

static class Display
{
    public static List<DISPLAY_DEVICE> GetGraphicsAdapters()
    {
        int i = 0;
        DISPLAY_DEVICE displayDevice = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
        List<DISPLAY_DEVICE> result = new List<DISPLAY_DEVICE>();
        displayDevice.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(displayDevice);
        while (NativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(null, i, ref displayDevice, 1))
        {
            result.Add(displayDevice);
            i++;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static List<DISPLAY_DEVICE> GetMonitors(string graphicsAdapter)
    {

        DISPLAY_DEVICE displayDevice = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
        List<DISPLAY_DEVICE> result = new List<DISPLAY_DEVICE>();
        int i = 0;
        displayDevice.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(displayDevice);
        while (NativeMethods.EnumDisplayDevices(graphicsAdapter, i, ref displayDevice, 0))
        {
            result.Add(displayDevice);
            i++;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static List<DEVMODE> GetDeviceModes(string graphicsAdapter)
    {
        int i = 0;
        DEVMODE devMode = new DEVMODE();
        List<DEVMODE> result = new List<DEVMODE>();
        while (NativeMethods.EnumDisplaySettings(graphicsAdapter, i, ref devMode))
        {
            result.Add(devMode);
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi James, I've edited my question with the code I've tried.
The display name is always the same - "cdd". I'm not even sure what is this name, cause the 2 monitors I have are named differently. @James Barrass

Comment: You're still passing null. A NULL value specifies the current display device on the computer on which the calling thread is running. You need to EnumDisplayDevices first.

Comment: I suspect the "cdd" stands for "Canonical Display Driver" (there's a system file in Windows called cdd.dll that is the canonical display driver). If anyone knows otherwise, please correct me.