# How to get list of available screen resolutions?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to list available video modes using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744541/how-to-list-available-video-modes-using-c)

My application needs a list of available screen resolutions. I've red this article ([link text](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/GemingLeader/display-settings-directx10122009114126AM/display-settings-directx.aspx)) but it didn't help me so much.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer has a working sample

[How to list available video modes using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744541/how-to-list-available-video-modes-using-c)

Comment: Then this is a dup, and this answer should be closed.

Comment: I have not seen it, sorry for dupe anyway.