# How to obtain the maximum screen resolution that a monitor supports using C#

Tags: c#, windows, screen-resolution

I need to obtain the Maximum supported screen resolution of a monitor, not the current resolution which is easy. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit: This is the updated solution that worked for me.**

```
        public Size GetMaximumScreenSizePrimary()
        {
            var scope = new System.Management.ManagementScope();
            var q = new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM CIM_VideoControllerResolution");

            using (var searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, q))
            {
                var results = searcher.Get();
                UInt32 maxHResolution = 0;
                UInt32 maxVResolution = 0;

                foreach (var item in results)
                {
                    if ((UInt32)item["HorizontalResolution"] > maxHResolution)
                        maxHResolution = (UInt32)item["HorizontalResolution"];

                    if ((UInt32)item["VerticalResolution"] > maxVResolution)
                        maxVResolution = (UInt32)item["VerticalResolution"];
                }

                log.Debug("Max Supported Resolution " + maxHResolution + "x" + maxVResolution);
            }
            return new Size(maxHResolution, maxVResolution);
        }
```

Comment: Not sure how to find that.. because OS only shows what it can support, to get the correct maximum resolution you may need to talk to monitor drivers.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744541/how-to-list-available-video-modes-using-c)

Comment: Isn't this the maximum screen resolution that your video card supports? I think this is NOT the maximum screen resolution your connected monitor supports. Sometimes those two resolutions match but not always.

Comment: If that is true, do you have any idea how to get the maximum resolution of the connected monitor?  So then perhaps the suggestion by Radik is more appropriate to my needs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744541/how-to-list-available-video-modes-using-c

Comment: I don't know if there is a API but there is a data structure called extended display identification data (EDID) which may help you.

Comment: I tested the solution using System.Management.ManagementScope by connecting a 16:9 monitor with a native resolution of 1920x1200 and a 4:3 monitor with a native resolution of 1280x1024 and the max resolution reported by the above code is 1280x1024 for the 4:3 monitor and 1920x1200 for the 16:9 monitor.  My guess is that somewhere in the API this is all figured out with the video controller and the monitor and then made available higher up through the Management interface.

Answer (score 3):

Get the results from the Management Scope.

```
            var scope = new System.Management.ManagementScope();
            var q = new System.Management.ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM CIM_VideoControllerResolution");

            using (var searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, q))
            {
                var results = searcher.Get();
                foreach (var item in results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item["Caption"]);
                }
            }
```

For more information about what information is available, refer to the [CIM_VideoControllerResolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page.

Comment: Thank you.  Your suggestion works great.  I edited my question above to include the modified code to retrieve the Max resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Obtain newWidth & newHeight of screen resolution as below and use them where u required

```
Screen scr = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
int newWidth = scr.Bounds.Width;
int newHeight = scr.Bounds.Height;
```

Comment: Thank you but the above only returns the current screen resolution not the maximum possible.

Answer (score -1):

Use primary screen property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen.aspx

Regards.

Comment: Thank you but the above only returns the current screen resolution not the maximum possible.