# How to keep proper aspect ratio of my application for a widescreen monitor?

Tags: c#, .net, resolution, screen-resolution

I have a widescreen monitor and I want to keep aspect ratio of my application and even handle "wrong" resolution that might be set.

For example monitor can display perfect circle with resolution 1920x1080.
But circle looks like ellipse when resolution 1400x1050 is set.

Our client is really picky on this and asks to determine and resize app to display perfect circle with any resolution and monitor we can handle.

[image]

So is it possible somehow to scale application and keep aspect ratio to display it with proper proportions on real device?

Comment: What is the *application*? Is it a `Form`? WinForms or WPF?

Comment: It's winforms application. But with WPF I have same behaviour.

Comment: windows does not know the physical dimensions of a screen, so if the resolution does not match, you can't detect that.

Comment: @ths sounds like truth, but I hope there is something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the `OnResize` event of the `Form` to preserve its aspect ratio:

```
private static readonly Size MaxResolution = GetMaxResolution();
private static double AspectRatio = (double)MaxResolution.Width / MaxResolution.Height;
private readonly PointF Dpi;

public YourForm() // constructor
{
    Dpi = GetDpi();
    AspectRatio *= Dpi.X / Dpi.Y;
}

private PointF GetDpi()
{
    PointF dpi = PointF.Empty;
    using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
    {
        dpi.X = g.DpiX;
        dpi.Y = g.DpiY;
    }
    return dpi;
}

private static Size GetMaxResolution()
{
    var scope = new ManagementScope();
    var q = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM CIM_VideoControllerResolution");

    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, q))
    {
        var results = searcher.Get();
        int maxHResolution = 0;
        int maxVResolution = 0;

        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            if (item.GetPropertyValue("HorizontalResolution") == null)
                continue;
            int h = int.Parse(item["HorizontalResolution"].ToString());
            int v = int.Parse(item["VerticalResolution"].ToString());
            if (h > maxHResolution || v > maxVResolution)
            {
                maxHResolution = h;
                maxVResolution = v;
            }
        }
        return new Size(maxHResolution, maxVResolution);
    }
}

protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResize(e);
    int minWidth = Math.Min(Width, (int)(Height * AspectRatio));
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
        Size = new Size(minWidth, (int)(minWidth / AspectRatio));
}
```

**EDIT**
Assuming that the maximum screen resolution reflects the "square" requirement, you could get all the screen resolutions as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537078/how-to-obtain-the-maximum-screen-resolution-that-a-monitor-supports-using-c-shar) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744541/how-to-list-available-video-modes-using-c). You only need to find the "maximum" of them.

Notice, that Windows usually doesn't have real DPI values, I use DPI only to compare the horizontal DPI with the vertical one.

Comment: You don't want to preserve the aspect ratio in pixels, you are trying to preserve aspect ratio in meters. Am i right?

Comment: Just try to set on widescreen monitor resolution 1400x1050 and display circle in form. It will be displayed like ellipse while device will automatically scale proportions. So we need to determine real device size and scale somehow from this value.

Comment: +Dmitry yes, sounds like correct. Короче суть в том, что на широкоформатном мониторе квадратные разрешения экрана автоматически растягиваются. Заказчик хочет в противовес этому "стягивать" наше приложение, чтоб все смотрелось пропорционально в реальном физическом мире)

Answer (score -2):

Get height of your window and scale the width as a fraction of the height, or the other way around, as desired.

```
void aspectRation(var width, var height){
    //Divide by 100 to get 1% of height, then multiply by (a number) to maintain ratio
    var newWidth = (height/100) * 80;

    //set the window size here
}
```

Setting the window size will depend on your application.

Comment: I know this formula. I want to determine how to scale application to display it properly on real wide device where "square" resolution is set. Monitor will automatically display "square" resolution with wrong proportions.

Comment: Surely you would need interaction between the monitor and your program in order to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, and sounds like I have to know real device proportions.

Comment: Use the screen density in pixels per cm/inch along with the screen size in pixels to calculate the screen size in meters and scale your application accordingly?

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/789093-how-get-monitor-size - this seems to explain how to grab both, at a quick glance :)