# How to get supported resolution of a specific monitor?

Tags: c#, monitor, screen-resolution, multiple-monitors, uid

I've seen this great post regarding the supported resolution :
[How to list available video modes using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744541/how-to-list-available-video-modes-using-c)

The problem that is gives me the supported resolutions of the screen that I'm running my .exe on.

I have 2 screens, and want to pass the screens "UID" or some other parameter and get the resolution by it.

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks!!

Comment: Thousands of examples with the [Screen class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen(v=vs.110).aspx), look also here on the right. Related column

Comment: You'll have to pinvoke EnumDisplayDevices() to get device names that you can pass as the 1st argument of EnumDisplaySettings().

Comment: I still doesn't answer my question (none of the related). I can get the monitor UID but I don't understand where it should go as a parameter. I saw that EnumDisplaySetting in the example that I added, has the first parameter as "null". Should this be the one changed? Not sure the UID is the "Device Name" that is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enumerate all display devices with EnumDisplayDevices API and then use DeviceName as first parameter for EnumDisplaySettings API, here is the code to get display device names:

```
  var displayDeviceNames = new List<string>();
  int deviceIndex = 0;
  while (true)
  {
    var deviceData = new DisplayDevice();
    deviceData.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DisplayDevice));
    if (EnumDisplayDevices(null, deviceIndex, ref deviceData, 0) != 0)
    {
      displayDeviceNames.Add(deviceData.DeviceName);
      deviceIndex++;
    }
    else
    {
      break;
    }
  }
```

Needed declarations:

```
[Flags()]
public enum DisplayDeviceStateFlags : int
{
  /// <summary>The device is part of the desktop.</summary>
  AttachedToDesktop = 0x1,
  MultiDriver = 0x2,
  /// <summary>The device is part of the desktop.</summary>
  PrimaryDevice = 0x4,
  /// <summary>Represents a pseudo device used to mirror application drawing for remoting or other purposes.</summary>
  MirroringDriver = 0x8,
  /// <summary>The device is VGA compatible.</summary>
  VGACompatible = 0x16,
  /// <summary>The device is removable; it cannot be the primary display.</summary>
  Removable = 0x20,
  /// <summary>The device has more display modes than its output devices support.</summary>
  ModesPruned = 0x8000000,
  Remote = 0x4000000,
  Disconnect = 0x2000000
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct DisplayDevice
{
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
  public int cb;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
  public string DeviceName;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
  public string DeviceString;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
  public DisplayDeviceStateFlags StateFlags;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
  public string DeviceID;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
  public string DeviceKey;
}

[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern int EnumDisplayDevices(string lpDevice, int iDevNum, ref DisplayDevice lpDisplayDevice, int dwFlags);
```