# Trouble Getting Available Screen Resolutions in C#

Tags: c#

I need to get the screen resolutions for a specific display on my system.
I found a great solution here which works great as is:
[How to list available video modes using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744541/how-to-list-available-video-modes-using-c)

However, when I substitute a display name for "null" in "Main" I get nothing back.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool EnumDisplaySettings(
          string deviceName, int modeNum, ref DEVMODE devMode);
    const int ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS = -1;

    const int ENUM_REGISTRY_SETTINGS = -2;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct DEVMODE
    {

        private const int CCHDEVICENAME = 0x20;
        private const int CCHFORMNAME = 0x20;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x20)]
        public string dmDeviceName;
        public short dmSpecVersion;
        public short dmDriverVersion;
        public short dmSize;
        public short dmDriverExtra;
        public int dmFields;
        public int dmPositionX;
        public int dmPositionY;
        public ScreenOrientation dmDisplayOrientation;
        public int dmDisplayFixedOutput;
        public short dmColor;
        public short dmDuplex;
        public short dmYResolution;
        public short dmTTOption;
        public short dmCollate;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x20)]
        public string dmFormName;
        public short dmLogPixels;
        public int dmBitsPerPel;
        public int dmPelsWidth;
        public int dmPelsHeight;
        public int dmDisplayFlags;
        public int dmDisplayFrequency;
        public int dmICMMethod;
        public int dmICMIntent;
        public int dmMediaType;
        public int dmDitherType;
        public int dmReserved1;
        public int dmReserved2;
        public int dmPanningWidth;
        public int dmPanningHeight;

    }


static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    DISPLAY_DEVICE device = new DISPLAY_DEVICE();
        device.Size = (ushort)Marshal.SizeOf(device);
        DEVMODE vDevMode = new DEVMODE();

        int i = 0;
        while (EnumDisplaySettings(@"\\.\DISPLAY1", i, ref vDevMode))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Width:{0} Height:{1} Color:{2} Frequency:{3}",
                                    vDevMode.dmPelsWidth,
                                    vDevMode.dmPelsHeight,
                                    1 << vDevMode.dmBitsPerPel, vDevMode.dmDisplayFrequency
                                );
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `when I substitute a display name for "null" in "Main" I get nothing back.` I am unclear what this sentence means. What is `null` referring to?

Comment: Post the code that doesn't work, not the code that works. Also note that the display name is kind of mandatory anyway when you're dealing with multi-display systems, unless you really know what you're doing. I'm thinking it might only work when the application is a GUI application, since it has to do with the display the UI (of the current thread) is running on - that doesn't apply to a console application, which doesn't own its own GUI.

Comment: Ah, no, I tried it with `null` and it works fine in a console application as well, at least on Windows 7 (what Windows are you using? Are you running the application elevated?). You *are* using `EnumDisplaySettings(null, i, ref vDevMode)` and not `EnumDisplaySettings("null", i, ref vDevMode)`, right?

Comment: You could try this for getting your screen resolution:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118682/68282

Comment: [Avoid re-inventing the wheel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was system configuration.

I was using a laptop with the screen closed and two external monitors.
When I opened the screen it started working.
I think it also a hardware issue because on my home (Desktop) system it worked as expected.