# How to detect available resolutions on users monitor?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, unity-game-engine, launcher

I am trying to essentially make a launcher for my Unity game that allows the user to adjust graphical and audio options. However, I can't seem to find a way to display all the possible resolutions the user's monitor supports. Is this possible at all?

Jonathan Palmer

Comment: Pretty sure this is the video I used to understand it myself (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOaYQrN1oYQ), but you can also use the display resolution dialogue if you want a 'launcher' for your game.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for [`Screen.resolutions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-resolutions.html)

> All full-screen resolutions supported by the monitor (Read Only).
>
> ```
> public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
> {
>     void Start()
>     {
>         Resolution[] resolutions = Screen.resolutions;
>
>         // Print the resolutions
>         foreach (var res in resolutions)
>         {
>             Debug.Log(res.width + "x" + res.height + " : " + res.refreshRate);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The Unity solution is [`Screen.resolutions`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-resolutions.html).

If you're looking for a solution before starting the Unity app, you have to use something native. On Windows you can try the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744541/how-to-list-available-video-modes-using-c).