# C# from lagging while resizing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, debugging, optimization

I'm using a background worker to run a loop refreshing a PictureBox.

While the backgroundworker is running, I experience the following 2 issues:

1. Delays when resizing the form to the point where the form could get hung for a few seconds.
2. Trouble finding points on the form's border from where it can be resized, for example
   when hovering on the form's border, it could take a few seconds for the cursor to update and
   indicate the form is sizeable, and sometimes the cursor wont update at all.

Things I tried:

- Invoking `SuspendLayout()`/`ResumeLayout()` in the form resize begin/end event handlers, didn't help.
- Enabling the 'DoubleBuffered' prop for the form, didn't help.
- Using a timer instead of a backgroundworker, but the the visuals were considerably slower than those produced by a backgroundworker running withtout delays.
  [In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-w8ABjm4sE&ab_channel=G4rbageMeal) I show how a background worker without delays performs comapred to a timer with the `Interval` set to 1.
- Adding `Thread.Sleep(1)` inside the backgroundworker after refreshing the PictureBox,
  and think it solved issues related form resize, but visuals are again much slower.

**My question: Is there a way to fix the from resize issues without slowing down visuals?**

Below is a minimalistic code example recreating the issues I'm having:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BGWDrawingTests
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BackgroundWorker bgw;
        bool someCondition = true;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartBGW_DoWork();
        }

        void StartBGW_DoWork()
        {
            // Start bgw and assign it the work 'BGW_DoWork'
            bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(BGW_DoWork);
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void BGW_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // Keep drawing stuff while some condition is met
            while (someCondition)
            {
                RefreshPicBox();
                // Adding the delay seems to fix the form resize bug,
                // but also drastically slows drawing.
                //Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }

        void picBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // Draw stuff
        }

        delegate void RefreshPicBoxCallback();
        void RefreshPicBox()
        {
            // Thread safe "picBox.Refresh()"
            if (picBox.InvokeRequired)
                picBox.Invoke(new RefreshPicBoxCallback(RefreshPicBox), new object[] { });
            else picBox.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

For a bit more context, I'll mention that the backgroundworker is used to run a force directed graph drawing algorithm.
The backgroundworker's actual DoWork method:

```
private void bgw_GraphViz(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (!formClosePending)
    {
        if (!formIsMinimized() && !graph.IsEmpty())
        {
            if (forcesEnabled) graph.ApplyForcesAndUpdatePositions();
            RefreshCanvas(); // Forces a redraw of the entire graph, the canvas is the PictureBox
            Thread.Sleep(1); // BUG - Delay needed to avoid form resize issues.
        }
    }
}
```

I noticed that when forces are enabled its more difficult to reproduce the bug,
and I think its becuase applying forces slows down the drawing frequency, basically
exactly what `Thread.Sleep(1)` achieves?

[In case it helps, here's the code of the Form including the method](https://github.com/garbagemeal/algorithm-visualizer/blob/master/AlgorithmVisualizer/Forms/GraphAlgoForm.cs) `bgw_GraphViz`

**EDIT:**

I added a new timer with the `Interval` set to 1 from where I `Invalidate` the `PictureBox`, instead of forcing redraws in the backgroundworker by `RefreshCanvas()`.

When I designed the graph drawing method, I thought it would be best to run a loop applying forces(moving nodes) by `ApplyForcesAndUpdatePositions()`, and then forcing a synchronous drawing of the graph.
The problem with this approach is that the rate at which forces are applied depends on the speed of drawing the graph(FPS).

Now because drawings of the graph are no longer made synchronously on the same thread, The rate at which `ApplyForcesAndUpdatePositions()` is invoked now only depends on the size of the graph and does not depend on the FPS, and thus nodes move extremley fast when the graph is small. [In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FguDjt2a5ns&ab_channel=G4rbageMeal) I first show how the drawing of the graph used to be, that is, when drawings of the graph are synchronous, and then show how it would work if drawings of the graphs were async. Note that in this video I only used a backgroundworker, but it does not reflect the current code I use.

Some of the things I tried:

- Adding delays after applying forces by `ApplyForcesAndUpdatePositions()`, This basically limits the calls to `ApplyForcesAndUpdatePositions()` at ~60 calls per sec, and the result was slow.
- Counting Paint events of the graph to limit calls to `ApplyForcesAndUpdatePositions()`, again could do no better than a hard limit of ~60 calls per sec.
- Binary semaphore/Lock/ManualResetEvent to sync the backgroundworker and the Paint event, again either hit a 60 call per sec hard limit or failed altogether.

I also considered using a `StopWatch`, but since `Thread.Sleep(1)` or `Task.Delay(1)` dont actually sleep for 1 millisec, and because I don't know of a way to "sleep" for less than 1 millisec, am currently unsure if the `StopWatch` is even applicable.

Honestly, I'm lost, I'm unsure how could I solve this problem.

Comment: Use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and set its `Interval` to 55, don't call `.Refresh`, call `.Invalidate` method instead in the `Tick` event. Using the [BufferedGraphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bufferedgraphics?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) could give you better results. If you need something better and faster in the WinForms world, then you have to deal with the DirectX. 
The WPF is an alternative.

Comment: Using the Background worker here was POINTLESS since you essentially have a tight loop whose sole job was to tell the UI thread to continuously do work via Invoke().  You can "fix" this by using a longer delay in your Sleep() call; I'd suggest nothing smaller than 50 or maybe even 100.  Additionally, if the processing done in your Paint() event is heavy, the form will still lag while it repaints.  You may need to rethink how you draw everything, only drawing parts that have changed, for instance.

Comment: Please note that even if you use a background thread, resizing by `Graphics.DrawImage` may cause lagging because `Graphics` uses process-wide locks. If this is the issue you are facing with, then you can use [this](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_BitmapExtensions_Resize.htm) extension method from my [drawing library](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing) ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing))

Comment: @dr.null I've edited the question to include a link showing the difference between a backgroundworker and a timer. Clearly the background worker is much faster according to the FPS estiamte and also feels much smoother? The timer's tick method example simply applies forces and then invalidates the PictureBox as you suggested, however the ```Interval``` is set to 1, as for the backgroundworker I've removed all delays. Also how could I benifit from the ```BufferedGraphics``` ?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Adding bigger delays would result in slower visuals. As for the Paint event it does draw the entire graph, but I think checking what needs to be redrawn might require much more time then drawing the entire graph. For exmaple when redrawing an edge I would have to check if it overlaps a vertex, And suppose there are n edges to redraw where n is larger then the number of vertices, wouldn't I have to do O(V^2) work to mark n edges for redraw?

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg I'm not entirely sure what do you mean by "resizing by Graphics.DrawImage", but in the form resize event handler I only update a "point" and do no additional drawing/resizing, and I don't use ```Graphics.DrawImage``` when drawing.

Comment: For now: 1) Don't `Thread.Sleep` the UI thread. 2) Call `Invalidate` rather than `Refresh` to update the drawing canvas. 3) You don't need to double-buffer the pbox because it is by default. 4) Replace `picBox.Invoke(...)` with `picBox.BeginInvoke(...)`. 5) Try to reduce the `Invalidate();` calls. For example, no need to call `graph.ApplyForcesAndUpdatePositions();` if the positions haven't changed. 6) If `RefreshPicBox()` is always called from the worker then you can omit `if (picBox.InvokeRequired)` because it is.

Comment: @dr.null I can't ommit the calls to ```graph.ApplyForcesAndUpdatePositions()``` because it moves vertices by applying forces, it does not however redraw the graph. I replaced ```RefreshPicBox()``` with ```picBox.Invalidate()```, and It does seem to fix the form resize issue, however because drawings of the graph are now asyc, it will apply lots of forces before a drawing of a graph is made. So the first few vertices i add will "teleport" to the center, and as the graph gets bigger and ```graph.ApplyForcesAndUpdatePositions()``` takes more time to compute, vertices seem to move slower.

Comment: @dr.null I didn't have enough space in the previous comment, but I'd like to add that for some reason replaing ```RefreshPicBox()``` with ```picBox.Invalidate()``` can somewhy cause the form to freeze when pressing a button.

Also I've uploaded a video to better show what I meant in this and the prevoius comment: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FguDjt2a5ns&ab_channel=G4rbageMeal

Comment: There's no reason to update the graphics faster than the refresh rate of the screen. at 60hz that's 16.67ms between updates. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744541/how-to-list-available-video-modes-using-c/744609#744609

Comment: Yes, `picBox.BeginInvoke` causes that delay. So, ignore 4 in my last comment. Again, the Form freezes because your while loop invokes a huge amount of UI refresh calls. You need to revisit your source code to find out when and where the drawing **really** needs an update. Without an accelerator (DirectX) and hardware aid (GPU), I'm sorry but I don't think so for such a project.

Comment: @Charlie I agree, but I didn't want to assume the refresh rate because it could also be 120 or 144 hz. Also im not sure if its just me, but I feel like 60 FPS has lots of tearing where as higher frame rates have less tearing.
Either way I think I've hard limited the FPS to ~60 by using a timer with the ```Interval``` set to 1 to redraw the graph asynchronously, instead of a backgroundworker forcing redraws of the graph synchronously. Also I have edited the question in an attempt to explain the problem I currently face.

Comment: @dr.null I think the issue of too many UI refresh calls (assuming you meant too many graph redraws) has been adressed by hard limiting the FPS to ~60 by using a timer with the ```Interval``` set to 1 to redraw the graph asynchronously, instead of a backgroundworker forcing redraws of the graph synchronously. Also I have edited the question in an attempt to explain the problem I currently face